# Totals on Invoice and Credit memo

Tags: invoice, pdf, creditmemo

I see that the totals on PDF invoices, and on credit memo are pulled from one same abstract.php

Can I somehow make different totals on credit memo than on invoice? is there a way to make a copy of abstract.php only for credit memos?

I need to display some negative valuues in front of totals on my credit memo, so thats why I need this.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know exactly which classes you are referring to `Abstract.php` is likely not called directly but extended from a different class. If that's the case I suggest you rewrite the class that is extending `Abstract` and overwrite the method that is in abstract.

So let's say you have the `abstract` class

```
class Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract
{
   public function getTotals()
   {
      [...]
      here the totals come from
      [...]
   }
}
```

and the `credit` class

```
class Mage_Sales_Model_Creditmemo extends Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract
{
   [...]
   the credit memo methods
   [...]           
}
```

You will need to rewrite the `Mage_Sales_Model_Creditmemo` class with your own extension. It would look something like this

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Creditmemo extends Mage_Sales_Model_Creditmemo
{
   public function getTotals()
   {
      [...]
      Here is your edited totals function
      [...]
   }
}
```